# Add two buttons in footer in the same row

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

hello I want to add two buttons on my ViewController programmatically like this [image]

What I have done is this

```
func createButton(buttonTitle: String,buttonAction: Selector) -> UIButton{
        let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/2, 48)
//       button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Variables.MONTESERRAT_REGULAR, size: 20.0)



        button.backgroundColor = UIColor().blueColor()       //top
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,10.0, 10.0, 0.0)
      return button
    }



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let footerView = UIView()
        footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 48)

  bottomButton = createButton("PUBLISH", buttonAction: "Publish")

   footerView.addSubview(bottomButton!)



        return footerView

}
```

At the moment it only prints one button. for second button I am doing this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            let footerView = UIView()
            footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 48)

      bottomButton = createButton("PUBLISH", buttonAction: "Publish")

 bottomButton2 = createButton("Delete", buttonAction: "Delete")

       footerView.addSubview(bottomButton!)
       footerView.addSubview(bottomButton2!)




            return footerView

    }
```

This code is not printing two buttons. just printing only one

Comment: What is the error that is printed?  (What is nil?)

Comment: @Daven sorry no error is coming. just two buttons are not showing up. it shows only one

Comment: Okay, I added my answer below.  I think the problem was that the buttons are showing over each other

Comment: The frame of two btns are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that both buttons have the same position, so one is showing above the other.

Try this:

```
    func createButton(buttonTitle: String,buttonAction: Selector, buttonNumber : Int) -> UIButton{

        let backgroundColor = buttonNumber == 0 ? UIColor.blueColor() : UIColor.orangeColor()
        let space : CGFloat = 5

        let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        let width = (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - space)/2

        let xPos = buttonNumber == 0 ? 0 : width + space
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0, width, 48)
        //       button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
//        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Variables.MONTESERRAT_REGULAR, size: 20.0)

        button.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,10.0, 10.0, 0.0)
        return button
    }
```

And then add it like so:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerView = UIView()
    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 48)

    bottomButton = createButton("PUBLISH", buttonAction: "Publish", buttonNumber: 0)

    bottomButton2 = createButton("Delete", buttonAction: "Delete", buttonNumber: 1)

    footerView.addSubview(bottomButton!)
    footerView.addSubview(bottomButton2!)

    return footerView

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. whats buttonNumber?.. it is giving me error

Comment: What is the error?  Did you replace both methods with the one I pasted above?  You're passing in which button you'd like - if it's the first button, the x position is 0.  If it is the second button (1) then it changes the x position

Comment: yeah I pasted But I am getting syntax error here

let xPos = buttonNumber == 0 ? 0 : width
you are not declaring buttonNumber to anything ..

Comment: @hellosheikh Did you paste the whole method?  I added a new parameter 'buttonNumber' in the method signature, so now it is - `func createButton(buttonTitle: String,buttonAction: Selector, buttonNumber : Int) -> UIButton`.  It works when I tried it

Comment: oh okay sorry..I'll do that

Comment: Thank you very much.. just one small request. both the buttons have the same color now. could you please tell me how can I have the different colors of both the buttons and have small space between them.

Comment: @hellosheikh Sure, I added new `space` and `backgroundColor` constants which you can change to how you like (you'll need to completely copy the method again).  Although, the more you change of each button, I recommend just creating the buttons without a method as they have less in common.  If this helps, please mark the answer as the solution :)